# Error HTTP 401.2 - Unauthorized with windows authorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7, windows-authentication

I to do:

> Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Internet
>   Information Services (IIS) Manager.  In the Connections pane, expand
>   the server name, expand Sites, and then select the site, application
>   or Web service for which you want to enable Extended Protection for
>   Windows authentication.   Scroll to the Security section in the Home
>   pane, and then double-click Authentication.  In the Authentication
>   pane, select Windows Authentication.  Click Enable in the Actions
>   pane.  Click Advanced Settings in the Actions pane.

after set in web.config `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

If I start app from VS2010 - All works well.
If else I start app from IIS I have problem.
Requested user data I enter Computer\NameUser.
then an error:

> Error HTTP 401.2 - Unauthorized You have no right to view this page
>   because of the inadmissibility of the authentication header.

**update:**

[image]

**update2:**
file: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config

```
<location path="windowsAuthTest">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" userName="User" password="[enc:AesProvider:BZ7e2mkTjJL7Wo8xMm2PQKZ2biP1nKB2SjAfw9WmJoBhkMbl4DYqEJU0bzIj3CxF:enc]" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" useKernelMode="false">
                    <extendedProtection tokenChecking="None" />
                    <providers>
                        <clear />
                        <add value="NTLM" />
                        <add value="Negotiate" />
                    </providers>
                </windowsAuthentication>
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

After that you access to security of your site you must to add right for the user windows.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5035520/588868).

Basically, that means that the authentication ticket does not match the expectation of the server.

You should force the server to use NTML or Kerberos (depending on your authentication strategy).

**[Edit]** as appcmd can be a bit obscure, here is the manual stop to force NTLM authentication.

1. Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`
2. Backup, Backup, Backup and rebackup applicationhost.config
3. To be sure backup again
4. Open the file applicationhost.config with your favorite xml editor
5. search for the node `<location path="Your web site name/yourapplication">`
6. Setup the correct authentication provider :

The important part is that there is the `<clear />` node. This will break inheritance from the global configuration.

This can be applied to the whole IIS server, or a specific web site, or (like here) a specific web application).

I'm not sure, but I wonder if this can be set in the web.config within the app directly instead of the IIS config file. This merits to be tested.

Comment: Steve B, I'm doing something wrong, but these methods do not help me

Comment: try, temporary, to activate basic authentication instead of windows authentication. I'm quite sure this will works. If I'm right, the only thing you have to do is `appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication /+"providers.[value='NTLM']" /commit:apphost`

Comment: ERROR (message: The new object add missing required attributes. Unable to add a copy of the input collection of type "add" with a unique key attribute "value" with value "NTLM"
. )

Comment: removed but this not helped me.